# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: using try, catch

Tags: java, android, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

When I got Images from server, some restaurants are have 1 menu, 4 menus,  5 menus, etc, respectively. So, I use `try catch` for IndexOutOfBoundsException but if the restaurant have 1 menu, it doesn't show another data (eg. location) in below of menu. Eg. first linearlayout is menu, second linearlayout is location, etc. If the restaurant have 4 menus, location is appear. When I run the restaurant have 1 menu, `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1`

In restaurant,

```
    "id": "1",
    "menus_count": 1,
    "menus": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "menuImage": "e90573d2662eaa8d35b35c9cfcde2ee0.jpg"
      }
    ],
```

In another restaurant,

```
    "id": "2",
    "menus_count": 5,
    "menus": [
      {
        "id": 22,
        "menuImage": "ee7e8f69f24dbba3c65d043192466be0.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "menuImage": "64eaeb5c50f38c94ea65fe7e412047be.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "menuImage": "5fc3b5f41a49da0281ee3f970cb64d26.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "menuImage": "e56fa9fcbdeec32a94216e080de35952.jpg"
      }
    ],
```

Restaurant Activity.java

```
try {
    if (restaurant.getMenus() != null && restaurant.getMenus().size() > 0) {
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(0).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_zero);
        linearlayout_menu_zero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(1).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_one);
        linearlayout_menu_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(2).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_two);
        linearlayout_menu_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(3).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_three);
        linearlayout_menu_three.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    txt_locality_township.setText(restaurant.getLocality() + ", " + restaurant.getTownshipName());
} catch (NullPointerException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In Verbose,

```
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at com.wpg.hungryhopper.RestaurantActivity$1.success(RestaurantActivity.java:219)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at com.wpg.hungryhopper.RestaurantActivity$1.success(RestaurantActivity.java:150)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5669)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
04-26 10:08:38.896 26119-26119/com.eg.restaurant W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Show your logcat.

Comment: Why?  We know which line the problem is on, and the reason for it.

Comment: And why don't you simply check if size is exactly 4 to only fetch those 4 entries then?

Comment: I check `restaurant.getMenus().get(0).getMenuImage() != null && restaurant.getMenus().get(0).getMenuImage().length() >0`. It doesn't work.

Comment: it's work, index 1 is means size of your menu must be 2 but you checked > 0, as list index is zero base if you want get first item in list you must get index of 0

Comment: `restaurant.getMenus().size() == 1, restaurant.getMenus().size() == 2, restaurant.getMenus().size() == 3 ,restaurant.getMenus().size() == 4,` Thanks

Comment: Your error is telling you exactly what's happening. The list size is 1 (which is > 0), and you're trying to call `get(1)` on it. Index 1 doesn't exist.

Comment: @Tr.Buu why don't you use a `RecyclerView` instead of `LinearLayouts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your logic, even if you have 1 entry for menu in the list you're still calling

```
restaurant.getMenus().get(2)
```

This will give array out of bounds exception

```
if (restaurant.getMenus() != null && restaurant.getMenus().size() > 0) {
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(0).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_zero);
        linearlayout_menu_zero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(1).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_one);
        linearlayout_menu_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(2).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_two);
        linearlayout_menu_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(3).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_three);
        linearlayout_menu_three.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

should be

```
if (restaurant.getMenus() != null && restaurant.getMenus().size() > 0) {
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(0).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_zero);
        linearlayout_menu_zero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(restaurant.getMenus().size()>=2){
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://ex}{ample.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(1).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_one);
        linearlayout_menu_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
if(restaurant.getMenus().size()>=3){
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(2).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_two);
        linearlayout_menu_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
if(restaurant.getMenus().size()>=4){
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(3).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_three);
        linearlayout_menu_three.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

    }
```

Code i wrote here is very bad, but my intentions are to show you how to fix this problem and why is this exception in your code, Also You can try to make ImageViews dynamically in your Linear layout to make this code better and that will provide you with the possibility of increasing number of images even if there are 100 menu pages without changing any code and having static menu pages in Layouts.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for populating [list](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) instead of using multiple `LinearLayout`. Because your menu items are dynamic. So, you can handle it using `RecyclerView`. If you post the screenshot then I might be give the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply place the line that updates the location on the top of if block.

> txt_locality_township.setText(restaurant.getLocality() + ", " +
>   restaurant.getTownshipName());

The reason location is not being updated is that if IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown it skips this code so location is not updated.

```
try {
    txt_locality_township.setText(restaurant.getLocality() + ", " + restaurant.getTownshipName());
    if (restaurant.getMenus() != null && restaurant.getMenus().size() > 0) {
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(0).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_zero);
        linearlayout_menu_zero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(1).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_one);
        linearlayout_menu_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(2).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_two);
        linearlayout_menu_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/uploads/menus/" + restaurant.getMenus().get(3).getMenuImage()).into(img_menu_three);
        linearlayout_menu_three.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

} catch (NullPointerException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```